How does a bipedal amphibian use its legs in water?
Ok so I'm writing a story with humanoid animals that developed in water but adapted to instead live near large bodies of water like lakes.  They have legs and arms as well as a tail (About 5'8feet (152cm~) tall, the tail being mostly muscle and around 3 feet(91cm~) long). The main problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how their legs should work.
The animals swim similarly to how dolphins swim. They have a more flexible spine, but given their legs must be at least somewhat rigid to support walking on land, I need to figure out what happens to them in water. I can't just have them get smushed up against the tail.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Saying that a tailed biped swims like a dolphin is akin to coming up with an amphibious, limbless dolphin and saying that it walks like an elephant or bounds like a kangaroo - the anatomy is incompatible with the type of movement.  Have you looked at how amphibious creatures with tails and legs (eg crocodiles) swim?  What is the issue with having your tailed humanoids use a similar action?

Frogs in  water use their front legs against their bodies and kick with the back legs; not the way humans kick, but with a splayed sweep. That would probably be a good model.

Look at Platypodes
The creature you are describing is biomechanically a lot like a platypus: they have four limbs and a tail that moves up and down to swim. Given this, a platypus-inspired swimming mode should give a good way to position the legs in swimming
